# Editting or Refreshing JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a simple slide program, and left side of my application, there is a `JList` which shows the slides on the current application. I can save and load the slides. The problem is, when I'm trying to load the slides from XML file, I cannot delete all items, in the JList, and add them. Because when I remove elements by `model.removeAllElements();` and then trying to add items by;

```
    for(int i=0; i<mL.size(); i++){
        model.add(i, "Slide No: " + i);
        slideCounter++;
    }
```

Then `valueChanged` function will be called, and because I'm getting elements from arrayList in that function, it gives `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Therefore, in my load method, I create a new empty list(dMode), then I initialize the list with the number of slides by:

```
    list = new JList(dMode);
    jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(list);
```

but I cant assign new list to the current list.

What is your advice, how should I solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: valueChanged of which class? Anyway, sounds like you'r doing something wrong in the code you are not showing - time for an sscce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either implement my own [ListModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) or I would bind the data to the list using [JGoodies Binding](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries.html). When using JGoodies your view model could fire a `PropertyChangeEvent` whenever your array contents changes and your view will then be updated automatically. E.g.

```
Bindings.bind(myJList, new SelectionInList<String>
    (beanAdapter.getValueModel("listContents"),
     beanAdapter.getValueModel("listSelection")));
```

with a view model class that has a property for the list contents and one for the current selection.